How does the inventory drop system work in Banana?
I've started playing Banana on Steam and I see the game is dropping items that land into my Steam Inventory.
How does the drop system work? Does it drop randomly, or do I need to click a certain amount of times? Is there a limit on the amount of drops per hours, per day, etc.?
I'd just like to get as much info about the drop system as possible.

The drop system has two timers: A regular drop and a rare drop timer.
When a timer is empty and the game is open, it'll drop an item from the respective pool and reset it to 3 and 18 hours respectively.
As for which bananas and the drop rates of each individual banana type every time you trigger a drop: that has not been disclosed by the developers, and is constantly rotating.
tl;dr every 18 hours, if you are constantly clicking and assuming lag is not a thing, you would have got 6 regular bananas and a rare banana.
Note: This "18 hours" is more like 18 hours and some seconds plus lag/load.
